# How can you loop through an array of address'?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to loop through an array of address' and do something with each address but I keep getting an error

```
    var r = profile[_profileID].responders;
    for (uint i=0; i<r.length; i++){
        address reps = profiles[i].rep;
```

the error is

```
TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
            address reps = profiles[i].rep;
```

.rep is a uint. profiles is a mapping (address, struct).

Comment: Well. Your error is right there. You say rep is a uint. you are trying to access address even though rep is a uint type. Moreover since profiles is a mapping, you need to access each profile by indexing with an  address. So if you dont know the address which maps to a specific profile, you cannot access the profiles mapping(NOTE: mappings are not the same as arrays. Mappings are hash tables which means that you can only access them by the indexing of the type you map with). So yeah, several errors in code. You need to access each mapping like profiles[some address].rep

Comment: Thankyou. var r is an array of address' is there no way of looping through it and using each address in each iteration or do they have to explicitly called?

Comment: Well, if r is an array of addresses, then you can get the address for the mapping by doing something like `address reps = profiles[r[i]].rep;` in your for loop. if that doesnt work you can try to set a variable in the loop as the address r[i], then try to access the mapping the address.

Comment: That was it, Thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after confirming in the comments, this is the answer.

1. rep is a uint. you are trying to access address even though rep is a uint type.
2. since profiles is a mapping, you need to access each profile by indexing with an address.
3. So if you dont know the address which maps to a specific profile, you cannot access the profiles mapping.

NOTE: mappings are not the same as arrays. Mappings are hash tables which means that you can only access them by the indexing of the type you map with

So, assuming `r` is an array of addresses, you can get the address for the mapping by doing something like `address reps = profiles[r[i]].rep;` in your `for` loop. if that doesn't work you can try to set a variable in the loop as the `address r[i]`, then try to access the mapping the address.

Comment: Thankyou, this is what it was in the end profiles[r.responders[i]].rep;